# Using DDMS - figuring who allocated the memory

Tags: android

I see that My app is allocating 28 MB of 1 byte array. 
How can I check what's the source of this memory allocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) .

You need to  dump hprof data and check in [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)